# Unable to execute a program from a service

Tags: c#, windows-services, external-process

I have a Windows service which I want to periodically execute an external program.  I'm currently doing this the usual way

```
Process program = Process.Start(@"C:\mpewatch\db_parameters\DBParameters.exe");
```

This doesn't seem to be working.  I'm executing this from a separate thread which is started in my service's `OnStart` handler.  Is there any conceptual problem with this?  Is it not possible to execute external programs from a service like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question didn't indicate the operating system.

On Windows XP, you can configure your Windows service to interact with the desktop by opening the service control panel, double-clicking your service, selecting the Log On tab, configuring the service to run as local system, and checking the checkbox.  It's pretty straightforward.  You might try testing with something like Notepad.exe just to see if you can get it working.

On Vista (and presumably Windows 7), however, you may be out of luck.  I have read that the ability for Windows services to interact with the desktop has been removed in Vista.  I forget what the terminology is, but basically services will run in "shell 0," whereas users will occupy "shell 1".  User applications will be able to communicate with services and vice versa using technology like WCF, but services will not be able to communicate directly with the desktop.  For example, any error boxes that pop up will have to be dealt with by swapping to "shell 0."  Again, this is based on something I read a few months ago, and I haven't gone looking at it again.  For me, I've structured my Windows service to be configured using WCF via a front-end app.

I'm sorry I don't have a link for you, but if your service will eventually have to migrate to a newer OS (or you are already there), this is something to check on.

Comment: That checkbox worked great, and the suggestion to test with Notepad was also very helpful.  Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 4):

You *can* execute external programs from a service, but there are security issues. For example, your service may be running under an account which does not have read access to the folder where the external program resides, even if your interactive account does have that access.

For test purposes, try to configure the service to run under your interactive account. If the program is invoked as expected, then the problem with the original account is that it does not have sufficient privileges to run the program.

Answer (score 1):

Another critical consideration with Windows Services is that there is no GUI.  Technically, there is an option to allow the service to interact with a local GUI, but you will not see it.  This is due to services running as the Local System user.

Within a service, any modal dialog box (OK, Cancel, etc) is considered an error.

Comment: But presumably not in a separate program spawned from a service.